Heirarchy address in reactjs
Can anyone help me? I'm trying to integrate hierarchy address on my react project where if user select country the next dropdown field will suggest all the state or provinces under that country and if user select specific state or provinces, the next input field or dropdown field will suggest all the municipalities and cities under that provinces.
Is there an api or libraries or tutorial that I can see so that I can make this feature?

Hi, Please see if this is helpful to you for the data fetching part. https://18.react.dev/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks#when-to-use-custom-hooks
